# Java script onkeyDown repalce character function not working well on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, replace, onkeydown

I have an asp text box for decimal numbers.
I have a jscript function to replace the num pad "." character by the decimal separator used in the user culture(ex: en-US -> decimal separator: "." pt-PT -> decimal separator: ',')

here's my function:

```
//method that substitutes num pad '.' with the current user culture decimal separator when num pad '.' key is hit

function onKeyDownPutDecimalSeparator(e, textBox) {

    var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    if (unicode == 110) {

        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancel = true;

        textBox.value = textBox.value.concat(decimalSeparator);
    }

}
```

this is working fine on most browsers, including chrome and IE8, but in IE9 instead of 
replacing, for ex. 1.2 -> 1,2, 
is doing something like:

1.2 -> 1,.2 and when the text box looses focus, 1,2

the final value "1,2" is what i want, but that middle step when the user can actually see "1,.2" it's just awfull

any tip on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
textBox.value = textBox.value.concat(decimalSeparator);
```

Try

```
textBox.value = textBox.value.replace('.', decimalSeparator);
```

Comment: won't work, when the code is executed ther's not a '.' yet, it seems to me the '.' is only writen after.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't replace chars before they are inserted. Try calling this function onKeyUp. Seems like a much cleaner solution. Oh, you should also try e.preventDefault() which should disable inserting the , alltogether. This should work in IE9 (can't test since I'm on OS X atm), but it should be like  `if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();` to prevent older IEs from creating an error.

Comment: onKeyUp is the way to go, works in every browser I tested. Not the solution I had in mind but better change now than further. tks